# Able to bring up a node js application in a container and a redis container using docker-compose.yml but unable to access application

Tags: node.js, docker

```
docker-compose up
```

Shows -

```
app_1    | Node server listening on port 3800 in 'development' mode
app_1    | node_redis: Warning: Redis server does not require a password, but a password was supplied.
app_1    | node_redis: Warning: Redis server does not require a password, but a password was supplied.
```

docker ps shows following -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9c3f8a951203        redis:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        6379/tcp            mvc20_redis_1
b242b37adf15        mvc-nodejs          "node app.js"            2 days ago          Up 6 minutes        9005/tcp            mvc20_app_1
```

docker-compose.yml contains following -

```
version: '2'


services:
  app:
    image: mvc-nodejs

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
```

Previously I used to access the application end points on http://localhost:3800.

But now it is not accessible. Is it because of the external port not being configured?

Earlier, before using docker-compose, I was specifying an external port while running a container like this -

```
docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

Do I need to do something similar?
Newbie here.

**Update**

Tried the port 9005 as well. Same result -

Could not get any response via Postman.

Comment: Have you tried configurate the network_mode? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your `app` service and expose the internal port like this:

```
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - 3800:3800
```

Where first `3800` is the port you're gonna access the app externally (host port), and the last `3800` is the port where your node app is listening to.